# Is there a way to write nested if based on calculation in Codeeffects editor?

Tags: c#, rule-engine, business-rules, codeeffects

I have to create a business rule for the below set of conditions, due to the limitation of nested-if I am unable to write the below rule. Could you please suggest a workaround for the below scenario? please note that these numeric values could be changed anytime through the rule editor.

```
if(CapitalAmt <= 100,000) then 
    value =100*NoOfMember
    if value >=15000
        fee = 15000
    else
        fee = value     
else if (CapitalAmt > 100,000) then     
    value =CapitalAmt/200
    if value >=15000
        fee = 15000
    else
        fee = value
```

Answer (score 0):

No, the Code Effects rule editor doesn't support nested IFs. With your use case, you can probably use the Ruleset mode to write multiple rules in the way that each next rule would evaluate the value set by the previous one. Read more about the editor modes in [this article](https://codeeffects.com/Doc/Business-Rule-Editor-Modes).